# How can i reinstall my mouse, which stopped working after a freeze?

Tags: mouse, crash

Some combination of things caused my machine to freeze, probably to do with the browser somehow. There were a number of tabs open in Chromium and Firefox, one had a live video stream, another had a CodePen project. The only other time i've it has become mostly unresponsive was when i had a website cross browser testing service open, also through CodePen. That time it recovered when i closed that tab. This time i did a hard restart, because i had no use of the mouse - and i was in a hurry to get my live video stream up again.

The mouse still doesn't work, although everything else is fine. I tried "sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all". I really don't know what i'm doing, but the reinstall seemed to execute correctly. I also have a Wacom tablet connected to the computer and i am using it for now - it works fine (well, as fine as it did before, there are minor issues i haven't gotten around to fixing).

How do i reinstall my mouse?

Update: The mouse is wireless and i assumed it would be detected again after the xorg reinstall. I never thought to switch it off and on again. So, that was silly, and now it is working fine. (And the system is fine.)

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes did you try all the relevant answers here?

Comment: @ElderGeek Gee... i wish i'd read that a long time ago... It's EXACTLY the kind of key advice you don't get when you are first getting into Ubuntu...

Comment: Glad to help. I still remember what it was like getting started (Granted that was before Ubuntu, back in the days of keypunch cards) ;-)

Comment: From what i could see, there are a lot of questions about mice and keyboards that don't work when the machine comes out of suspend, but none for when it has had a cold-reboot.

Comment: Please let us know if that resolves this problem for you. or if not, reference it when you [edit] your question. The more information we get, the better we can help you. Don't be hesitant to search for the minor issues you haven't got around to fixing as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, isn't it too late for any of the solutions in the community wiki? Or do you mean for the suspend problem solutions? Because i already did a xorg reinstall...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22820/discussion-between-elder-geek-and-briligg).